# My Mathematical Symbol Recognition Program not Predicting Handwritten Data Well

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am making an optical character recognition program using machine learning with tensorflow in python. My training data comes from Kaggle's handwritten math symbols dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/xainano/handwrittenmathsymbols/data#) and I am only using numbers, the addition sign, minus sign, and times sign from there. How I made my neural network is below.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(14, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
#print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

The issue I am facing is how although with this model my training and validation accuracy are extremely high (around 97%), when I use my handwritten digits it miss classifies most of them. My training and validation are both from the Keras dataset. I used the predict function with the model on my handwritten data. My handwritten math symbols are quite like the training data being a picture of the same size as the training and validation data, same white background, and drawn using my Microsoft pen. Can you guys please assist me for what can I do to be able to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Does the dataset have class imbalance? Please add AUC, Precision, Categorical Accuracy values. Also try a deeper network with a few more Conv2D layers, more hidden nodes and batch normalization for speedup.

Comment: Since the result on the validation set are good, I think it suggests that your handwritten pictures are not distribute the same as the training data. Are you sure you did the exact same pre-processing as you did during training (for example - normalizing the values to a certain range like [-1,1])?

Comment: I am very sure I did the exact same preprocessing with things like normalization. Doing class balance did help however I am going to add more data to further balance it. Also adding another Conv2D layer did help. Thank you guys!